# How to create secret session keys (S-ENC, S-MAC and S-DEK) using card-challenge and card-cryptogram?

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, apdu, globalplatform

I have a microcontroller(msp430) and a smartcard(se050), and I am sending APDUs from micro controller to the smartcard using Code Composer Studio on my windows computer.

I am trying to create a secure channel (SCP03) using AES symmetry key. I have created a session using this AES key on the smart card and now to perform mutual authentication I have sent **'INITIALIZE UPDATE'** command APDU to smart card

Initialize Update APDU:

```
80 50 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And the response from the card is:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 60 7E 25 31 3D BE 63 59 BE 34 AA 4B C0 F2 B9 27 B4
```

where

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`  = **Key Diversification Data**

`00 03 60` = **Key information**

`7E 25 31 3D BE 63 59 BE`  = **card challenge**

`34 AA 4B C0 F2 B9 27 B4`  = **card cryptogram**

Now, I want to check if card cryptogram is correct or NOT? For that I need to create **secret session keys (S-ENC, S-MAC, S-DEK)** and the card cryptogram in order to authenticate the card.

Also I need to create **'Host Cryptogram'** that I need to resend to the smart card in '**EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE**' command.

How can I generate these things in code composer? Are there any C-libraries that I can import in my codes to generate these keys and cryptograms?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a while a ago and recently updated the [GlobhalPlatform C Library](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform). Here is an [Overview Page](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/) and here is the [API documentation](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/api/index.html). For your problem [mutual authentication](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/api/globalplatform_8h.html#a04ec0caaa3d78ae71bde0843f626b2ca) is a good starting point.
Remember that you can generate also more convenient project files for Visual Studio or Eclipse with `cmake -G "..."` to have a good way of browsing the project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have written a C code in code composer that sends APDUs to smart card from micro controller. I also sent the 'INITIALIZEUPDATE ' command. in the response from the smart card I got (card cryptogram, card challenge, diversification data), now I need to create session encryption key S-ENC, card cryptogram for comparison with the received card cryptogram from smartcard. I am trying to find a way how can I implement in C, so that I can formulate External Authenticate command.

Comment: So, you do not want to use the full library but your goal is to use code fragments to support your needs? Look into the file `globalplatform.c` in the `mutual_authentication` function, which references code from `crypto.c` which contains the operations you are searching. If your goal is to add later more GP functions instead of replicating the code, trying to port the library to your platform might be the smarter approach. The GP library is using the LGPL license, i.e. linking to closed source works, copying source code fragments 1:1 would require to publish the work also under LGPL or GPL.